# How 2FA with Biometrics improve security?

Tags: authentication, account-security, multi-factor, biometrics

Where I work, this is the passwordless registration/login flow for our Mobile App

1. A user registers with a username and a phone number. An SMS OTP is sent to the phone number to verify it.
2. Initial login: The user logs in to the mobile app with its username. The app sends an OTP code to the registered mobile number.
3. After login, the app prompts the user to enable a Biometric factor and a PIN as fallback for enhanced security
4. Next time the user logs in, he has to be in possession of the phone number (first factor) and complete the Biometric challenge (second factor).

The process seems pretty standard. We have

- Initial login

  - Username + Mobile OTP (something you have)
- Subsequent Logins

  - Biometric/PIN (something you are or know) bound to something you have (the mobile device where the biometric/PIN is setup)

But how is the biometric bringing any security value beside being more "user friendly" than the PIN. If the biometric fails it falls back to the PIN. So the PIN is the real factor.

Now consider the following threat

Your phone get stolen. The first security factor is now compromised. The thief can access the mobile app in two ways:

**Access the account from the stolen device**

1. If the phone is locked by a PIN, then the App is already protected by the device PIN
2. In case of phone jacking, the PIN might be known to the thief, putting the app behind a biometric/PIN is useless.

**Perform a first-time login from another device with your SIM card**

- The thief can do a SIM Swap and first-time login on a new device by receiving the OTP on the SIM. In that case, the biometric/PIN is not a safeguard anymore.

A third solution would be to ask the user to input a user-defined PIN that is stored remotely on my backend. But then, it is not bound to the device anymore. It becomes a simple password.

So, how biometrics is supposed to improve security? What is the correct workflow used by banks?

Comment: Biometrics are convenient not really that secure. And convenience is actually a very good property because 90% of the people are extremely lazy in terms of security.

Comment: Anyway when comparing security you need first define your threat model. What can the attacker do and what can't they do? What does the attacker know?  If in your scenario you assume that the attacker can know any PIN/password of the user, that they can steal/infiltrate the user device, that they can SIM swap any SIM etc then you will end up to the conclusion that you should not secure your application at all because there is no way to win and anything you do is useless... but is this a reasonable scenario?

Comment: So the PIN for the app is pulled from the PIN from the device? That's not clear from your description. Or is the biometrics/PIN step simply the ***local device*** authentication? You need to make it clearer ***what*** is doing the authentication of the biometrics and PIN. Your threats from a stolen device aren't clear. Consider also the trend of stealing a phone while it's in use, meaning the thief gets an unlocked phone.

Comment: Your SIM swap scenario also has some problems: 1. SMS OTP has long been considered insecure. 2. you don't mention a process to authorise an ***existing*** account on a ***new*** phone when it has already been set up. That's not biometrics' fault.

Comment: Rule of thumb (literally): biometrics doesn't work as a secret (e.g. a password), biometrics works to re-enforce identity (e.g. username).

Comment: The advantage of biometrics is that it is very convenient for the user, so they can afford to use more inconvenient + more secure passcodes.

Comment: @schroeder Yes, currently the app is protected by Biometrics, which falls down to the device PIN. So in case of a stolen device + PIN knows from the attacker (or the app is stolen while unlocked), the app is no more protected. This is why bank apps implement an app-specific PIN (different from the device PIN) when the Biometric fails. Thus, that PIN is no more tied to the device but I guess this is a simple 6-digits password. Meaning that the protection via biometrics, which is supposed to be more secure, ends up being a 6-digits passoword.

Comment: @schroeder And regarding the SMS OTP, how could it be more secure? The process of authorizing a new device is what I called "Initial login". This is done via OTP (after you register with a username and a mobile phone) and before you setup your biometric/PIN.

Comment: "the app is protected by Biometrics, which falls down to the device PIN" -- this is causing me more confusion. Why is this split? Why is the auth auth tied to device auth? Or is the app relying on the device auth? I think the latter is what you are trying to say.

Comment: You cannot secure SMS. The better approach is to send an email, at least.